# What is the meaning of --> or <-- (double hyphen) in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I understand Cypher queries that use single hyphen such as `->` or `<-` to indicate relationship direction.  However, today I saw a query that used double hypens like `-->` and `<--`.  What does it mean?  Is it same as single hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is short form for, `-[]->` or `<-[]-` Basically, where you don't care what type of relationship is between the two nodes.

See, https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#outgoing-relationships